# Access-Control-Allow-Headers in ServiceHTTP (POST) in agular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, http, servicio

Alquien me podria ayudar tengo un problema. Pero no lo puedo interpretar.

**user.service.ts**

```
  postUser(user:User):Observable<User[]>{
  let body = JSON.stringify(user);
  let headers = new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });

  return this._http.post<User[]>(this.listaUserURL, body, { headers })
  //.pipe(map( res => {return res}));
  .pipe ();
}
```

**usuario.component.ts**

```
saveUser() {
    this._appUserService.postUser(this.user)
.subscribe((data :User[]) => {console.log(data)});
}
```

**ERROR**
Este es el error que me sale

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/user' from origin 
  'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field 
  Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight 
  response.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando haces una petición HTTP desde un navegador web usando Javascript y el método XMLHttpRequest (mecanismo también conocido como AJAX, y usado por muchos *frameworks* javascript, Angular entre ellos), el navegador verifica si la URL a la que haces la petición es la misma que la que muestra la barra de navegación del navegador (que es lo que se llama el *origin*).

En tu caso no son la misma, debido a que son diferentes puertos.

Cuando no es la misma URL, el navegador se toma ciertas precauciones antes de permitirle esa petición al javascript. Lo primero que hace es realizar al servidor una petición `OPTIONS`, en vez de `POST` y después examina las cabeceras de la respuesta del servidor. Entre ellas busca ciertas cabeceras especiales que significan que el servidor le "da permiso" para continuar. Sólo entonces hace la petición `POST` en cuestión.

En tu caso, tu servidor no ha enviado la cabecera `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` que es una de las que espera el navegador, por lo que el navegador aborta la petición.

Todo este protocolo y las cabeceras involucradas se conocen bajo el nombre de CORS, por si necesitas buscar información para averiguar cómo se incluyen esas cabeceras en el *framework* particular que use tu servidor.

Comment: Si me parese que tiene razón en mi API REST me sale -> OPTIONS /user 200 5.551 ms - 13

Comment: ¿tendria que instalar cors  a mi API REST?

Comment: @JhonnySAN Sí, tienes que investigar la documentación del _framework_ que implementa tu API REST para buscar como habilitar CORS (lo que significa, aceptar la petición OPTIONS y responder con las cabeceras adecuadas)

Answer (score 1):

En tu REST API, debes aceptar CORS, para que acepte peticiones de tu localhost o tu url de desarrollo. Te adjunto este link donde explica como activar CORS dependiendo de tu backend.

[ENABLE CORS](https://enable-cors.org/)