# CORS JQUERY como solucionar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo el problema de que estoy desarrollando un consumo de web service para una pagina, el web service me lo esta proporsionando una entidad, de las que solo te dice aqui esta la URL mira tu como le haces, al inicio consumi con Java pero el proceso es muy lento, luego consumi con Jquery mucho mas rapido solo que este me da problemas de CORS, los msj que recibo son

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dominiodelainstitucion' from origin 'https://midominio' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cannot parse Access-Control-Allow-Methods response header field in preflight response.*

*jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2          POST https://farm3.sat.gob.gt/retencion-liberacion-ws/rest/privado/retencionLiberacion/consultar net::ERR_FAILED*

y por el momento este es mi codigo que lo genera POSTMAN

```
var settings = {
                "url": "https://farm3.sat.gob.gt/retencion-liberacion-ws/rest/privado/retencionLiberacion/consultar",
                "method": "POST",
                "timeout": 0,
                "headers": {
                    "Authorization": "Basic MzEkjhlkjhkj5hYzIwMTUr",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Cookie": "visid_incap_2112329=0xk+tVssSjegRxb6moVvoquKumAAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABebEr5ELkke+K1Kp+CTHG/"
                },
                "data": JSON.stringify({
                    "noContenedor": "TCNU1601505"
                }),
            };

            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
```

quiero destacar que no tengo acceso al servidor donde se aloja este web services, yo estoy tratando de consumirlo de postman funciona bien pero ya al subirlo a la pagina es donde muestra los errores

Comment: Lo he probado y tienes razon, solo funciona en postman, pero es raro... osea, yo veo todo super bien, ya probe tambien usando fetch y nada... aparece un error de `GET` en mi caso, pero yo al igual que tu estoy usando `POST` para la peticion y no `GET`.

Comment: Tal vez esto sirve? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/213752/access-control-allow-headers-in-servicehttp-post-in-agular-7

Comment: @Alfabravo lei por ahi un post que decia que postman no tenia problemas con en este caso el origen, puesto que la forma en la que envia las cabeceras es reconocida como si fuera el mismo origen?, la verdad no le entendi bien al post, pero no tiene mucho sentido para mi que eso sea cierto, de todas maneras, leyendo el post que enlazaste, yo me pregunto lo siguiente... para que entonces existe una autorizacion y una API si no puede usarse o acceder al recurso desde otro origen?, eso tampoco tiene sentido para mi... pienso que es mas bien un error de cabeceras, alguna especial que falta...

Comment: @Alfabravo lo otro es que te iba preguntar si sabias la forma en la que postman ejecuta esa peticion POST, porque por ej, yo la he ejecutado con exito desde postman, asi como el `OP`, no se si en este caso se trata de que postman se salta las cors o hace brujeria con el origen o simplemente al no hacer una peticion del tipo `XMLHttpRequest` si no otro tipo de peticion este no tiene estos problemas con los cors, si este es el caso... que tipo de peticion realiza postman y porque funciona?, OMG, presiento que esto de por si solo puede ser otra pregunta nueva xd

Comment: La autorización y el cross-origin son configuraciones separadas y es responsabilidad de quien mantiene una API el asegurar que las dos cosas funcionen juntas. Si espero usos desde sitios de terceros, debo configurar la política de forma que los encabezados le digan al navegador qué hacer (que es lo que pasa en tu caso, el navegador **honra** los headers; a postman le da un poco lo mismo)

Comment: @Alfabravo Ohh... mucho mas sencillo de lo que pense...